# Matlab: Help neede to initialize matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement the basic Equations for Kalman filter for the following 1 dimensional AR model:

```
x(t) = a_1x(t-1) + a_2x(t-2) + w(t)  

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t);
```

The KF state space model :

```
x(t+1) = Ax(t) + w(t)

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t)

w(t) = N(0,Q)

v(t) = N(0,R)
```

where

```
 % A - state transition matrix
% C - observation (output) matrix
% Q - state noise covariance
% R - observation noise covariance
% x0 - initial state mean
% P0 - initial state covariance
```

The code for the prediction and update are:

```
function [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x, P, F, Q)
xpred = A*x;
Ppred = A*P*A’ + Q;
function [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z, H, R)
nu = y - C*xpred; %% innovation
S = R + C*Ppred*C’; %% innovation covariance
function [xnew, Pnew] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, n
u, S, C)
K = Ppred*C’*inv(S); %% Kalman gain
xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
Pnew = Ppred - K*S*K’; %% new covariance
```

I am trying to follow the implementation https://github.com/cswetenham/pmr/blob/master/toolboxes/lds/kalmansmooth.m  but getting confused since the parameters A,C are given as matrices.

Do I have to represent A,C as matrices? How do I represent A,C , Q,R for my case?

How do I initialize A,C,Q,R? Since, I have only one variable, Q,R should be 1 by 1. But, what about the others?
 Please help.

UPDATE: Here is the full implementation

```
%%% Matlab script to simulate data and process usiung Kalman for the state
%%% estimation of AR(2) time series.
% Linear system representation
% x_n+1 = A x_n + Bw_n
% y_n = Cx_n + v_n
% w = N(0,Q); v = N(0,R)
clc
clear all

T = 100; % number of data samples
order = 2;
% True coefficients of AR model
  a1 = 0.195;
  a2 = -0.95;

A = [ a1  a2;
      0 1 ];
C = [ 1 0 ];
B = [1;
      0];

 x =[ rand(order,1) zeros(order,T-1)];



sigma_2_w =1;  % variance of the excitation signal for driving the AR model(process noise)
sigma_2_v = 0.01; % variance of measure noise


Q=eye(order);
P=Q;




%Simulate AR model time series, x;



sqrtW=sqrtm(sigma_2_w);
%simulation of the system
for t = 1:T-1
    x(:,t+1) = A*x(:,t) + B*sqrtW*randn(1,1);
end

%noisy observation

y = C*x + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,T);

R=sigma_2_v*diag(diag(x));
R = diag(R);

z = zeros(1,length(y));
z = y;

 x0=mean(y);
for i=1:T-1
[xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q);
[nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z(i), C, R);
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
end

%plot
xhat = xnew';


plot(xhat(:,1),'red');
hold on;
plot(x(:,1));



function [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q)
xpred = A*x0;
Ppred = A*P*A' + Q;
end

function [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, y, C, R)
nu = y - C*xpred; %% innovation
S = R + C*Ppred*C'; %% innovation covariance
end

function [xnew, Pnew] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C)
K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain
xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance
end
```

I have 3 problems:
(1) Is the initialization of the matrix R correct in terms of dimension and values?

```
R=sigma_2_v*diag(diag(x));
R = diag(R);
```

where x is the clean time series.
(2) When creating the noisy observation of the time series, I have used  a different variance other than R. I have used sigma_2_v. Should I be using R or sigma_2_v? This is the line where I have created noisy time series

```
y = C*x + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,T);
```

(3) The code is throwing the error

```
Error using inv
Matrix must be square.

Error in innovation_update (line 2)
K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain

Error in Kalman_run (line 65)
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to represent a given AR process as a state space model but I believe you'll have to have a 2 dimensional state representation if it's an AR(2) process (which your model is).  So A, C and Q will need to be matrices.

You have scalar observations and so C will be a 1x2 matrix.

- x should be a 2 dimensional vector of the form [x(t); x(t-1)].  The first element is the value of x at time t from the AR model and the second element is x at time t-1.
- A is of the form [a_1 a_2;1 0].  You can see that Ax is [a_1x(t)+a_2x(t-1);x(t)].  So after applying A to the state x the first element is the predicted next value of x (from the AR model a_1x(t)+a_2x(t-1)) and the second element is x at time t i.e. the elements have been shifted down.
- C can be [1 0] i.e. the observation y at time t is simply the first element of the state vector x.  Multiplying the state x by C should give use the observation of the state, here we want simply want to observe what the state is at time t and doing [1 0][x(t);x(t-1)] is just x(t).

A, Q, C and R can be learnt from data (e.g. as described [here](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/zoubin/course04/tr-96-2.pdf)) or set using prior knowledge of your system.

Just because you have one observed variable at each time step doesn't mean Q and R are 1.  Q is the system noise covariance and R is the observation noise covariance - setting them to one just specifies the covariance and doesn't do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 2 Questions, can you please clarify? (1)I need to give initial values for covariance matrices, Q and R as well. So, what should they be and the dimension? Will it be 2 by 2 i.e p by p if p is the order of the AR model? (2) In general, will the dimension of the parameters (state transition matrices) A, C  be 1*number of variables?  Can you please explain a bit more on how you have specified A,C?

Comment: If the dimensionality of your state space is p and the dimensionality of your observation space is q then the initial state covariance and Q will be p x p.  C is q x p (applying matrix C to x should transform to the observation space).  R is q x q (i.e. scalar in this case).  I've edited my answer for the 2nd part.

Comment: Sorry for replying in late, as I was implementing the code based on your answer. I am having some difficulties due to the dimension and initialization of the matrices. The code is throwing an error. Could you please help me out with this? I have provided the code in the Question. Thank you.

Comment: (1) and (2): Since your observation space is one dimensional i.e. scalar then R should be 1x1 and can be set to R=sigma_2_v.  (3) I suspect this is because S is a scalar value and not a matrix, whilst inv expects a matrix - `K=(Ppred*C')/S` will do.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. The error has gone. One last Question, if you don't mind to look into. However, I am getting  2 by 2 matrix for the xnew which is the updates for the state from the function innovation_update: xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
. I was thinking of plotting the estimates w.r.t to the true state. How can I generate the values from xnew (xhat) . Thank you so much!

Comment: You could plot the updated observations `C*xnew`.  It would also be good to plot the uncertainty on those values by computing the variance `C*P*C'` and using the square root of that as the size of some error bars centered on `C*xnew`.

Comment: I have posted a new Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955318/matlab-how-do-i-simulate-the-model-after-state-estimation-from-kalman-filter since C*xnew does not give a time series as xnew is not a vector. Maybe I need to initialize a new variable? Also, I have never worked with error bars and donot understand the centered part. Could you post this as an answer to the new Question in details? Appreciate your prompt answers. Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: I'll take a look... there's an issue I didn't spot with your A matrix - the second row should be 1 0 and not 0 1.