# Matlab: How do I simulate the model after state estimation from Kalman filter

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement the basic Equations for Kalman filter for the following 1 dimensional AR model:

```
x(t) = a_1x(t-1) + a_2x(t-2) + w(t)  

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t);
```

The KF state space model :

```
x(t+1) = Ax(t) + w(t)

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t)

w(t) = N(0,Q)

v(t) = N(0,R)
```

where

```
 % A - state transition matrix
% C - observation (output) matrix
% Q - state noise covariance
% R - observation noise covariance
% x0 - initial state mean
% P0 - initial state covariance

%%% Matlab script to simulate data and process usiung Kalman for the state
%%% estimation of AR(2) time series.
% Linear system representation
% x_n+1 = A x_n + Bw_n
% y_n = Cx_n + v_n
% w = N(0,Q); v = N(0,R)
clc
clear all

T = 100; % number of data samples
order = 2;
% True coefficients of AR model
  a1 = 0.195;
  a2 = -0.95;

A = [ a1  a2;
      1  0 ];
C = [ 1 0 ];
B = [1;
      0];

 x =[ rand(order,1) zeros(order,T-1)];



sigma_2_w =1;  % variance of the excitation signal for driving the AR model(process noise)
sigma_2_v = 0.01; % variance of measure noise


Q=eye(order);
P=Q;




%Simulate AR model time series, x;



sqrtW=sqrtm(sigma_2_w);
%simulation of the system
for t = 1:T-1
    x(:,t+1) = A*x(:,t) + B*sqrtW*randn(1,1);
end

%noisy observation

y = C*x + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,T);

%R=sigma_2_v*diag(diag(x));
%R = diag(R);

R = var(y);
z = zeros(1,length(y));
z = y;

 x0=mean(y);
for i=1:T-1
[xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q);
[nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z(i), C, R);
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
end

%plot
xhat = xnew';


plot(xhat(:,1),'red');
hold on;
plot(x(:,1));



function [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q)
xpred = A*x0;
Ppred = A*P*A' + Q;
end

function [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, y, C, R)
nu = y - C*xpred; %% innovation
S = R + C*Ppred*C'; %% innovation covariance
end

function [xnew, Pnew] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C)
K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain
xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance
end
```

Question: I want to see how close the estimated state `xnew` is to the actual state `x` by a plot. But, the `xnew` returned by the function `innovation_update` is a 2by2 matrix! How do I simulate a time series with the estimated values?

Comment: The input  `x =[ rand(order,1) zeros(order,T-1)]` is also a 2 x 2 array, so if you don't understand why that is 2 x 2 you probably won't understand why the output is 2 x 2 . My suggestion is understand your inputs first.

Comment: @TryHard: x is not a 2 by 2 array. I checked again and it gives me 2 by 100 matrix where the first and second elements of the first column are random numbers.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Unless I am again mistaken it's actually initialized to a 2 x 1 vector, namely `rand(order,1)`. The rest of the array are zeros to preallocate space for the evolving state.

Comment: Doing  rand(order,1) means only the element of the first row and second row of the first column have random values initialized to them. The rest are zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You don't need to initialise `x` to anything, just set the initial state `x(:,1)` and the "simulation of the system" loop will fill in the rest.</s>  Oops, I see you were already doing that!

Later, in the loop that infers the state `xnew` from the noisy observations `y` you can add the line:

```
[xnew, P] = innovation_update(xpred, Ppred, nu, S, C);
yhat(i) = C*xnew; % Observed value at time step i, assuming inferred state xnew
```

Finally, you should plot `yhat` and `y` for comparison.

If you want to add error bars for the uncertainty on the estimate then you should also store `Phat(i) = sqrt(C*P*C')` and call `errorbar(yhat,Phat)` instead of `plot(yhat)`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. (1) I corrected the second row of initial A matrix to 1 0. (2) The answer does not work because xnew returned by the function innovation_update is 2 by 2. But, yhat should be 1 by T vector. Thus, there is an error

Comment: Before the loop containing the call to `innovation_update` you should initialise `yhat` to be a 1xT vector.  Inside the loop we're just writing to the `i`-th element.  `xnew` should be a 2x1 vector.

Comment: I did the initialization of yhat. I don't know why xnew is coming to be 2by2 instead of 2 by 1. All this trouble is due to xnew. Can you please check the code and esp. the function predict since it is there that  xpred = A*x0 I am getting a 2 by 2 instead of 2 by 1.

Comment: It looks like you need to step through your code, maybe starting with the dimensions of x0 (since `A` is 2x2).

Comment: x0=mean(y); a scalar based on the mean of the measurements y. Is this wrong?

Comment: know my mistake now. I was under the impression that since the states are hidden, how do I know about its mean in order to pass it to the filter. I think x0 = mean(x,2) and so xpred is 2 by 1 now. Everything is now ok

Comment: But, there is no errorbars which I can see. corrcoef(y,YHAT)

[    1.0000    1.0000
    1.0000    1.0000 ]. Both YHAT and Y overlap each other and so I think there is no uncertainty. What is actually happening? The filter removed the measurement noise completely? Can you please throw some insights?

Comment: `y` and `yhat` will be close to each other if there isn't much noise in the system - try increasing `sigma_2_v` and/or `sigma_2_w` and see if `y` and `yhat` diverge.  Also see if `Phat` increases as you increase the noise covariances (it should).

Comment: Hello once again. I have implemented the code for Kalman filter, smoothing & parameter estimation based on your answers to my 2 Questions. Now, the problem is logical: If I initialize Predict with x0 = mean(x,2) then there is no problem with the filtering. But, if I initialize x0 = mean(y) then there is error in the multiplication yhat = C*xnew because xnew is 2 by2, instead of being 2 by1. So, what should be x0? Then other problem is that the smoothing and estimation do not work. Proper results is not coming.

Comment: It will be really kind of you and helpful if you can please go through the Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153993/matlab-help-in-proper-execution-of-kalman-filter-and-parameter-estimation ? Thank you for your help and time.