# Matlab: Program returns garbage values, Help in proper execution of Kalman Filter and parameter estimation

Tags: matlab, implementation, kalman-filter

I have implemented the Kalman Smoothing with Expectation Maximization based on the Paper [Parameter Estimation for Linear dynamical system](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.55.5997). All notations are based on this paper. 
The model is an IIR (AR(2)) filter

```
y(t) =  0.195 *y(t-1) - 0.95*y(t-2) + w(t)
```

The state space representation:

```
x(t+1) = a^Tx(t) + w(t)

y(t) = C(t) + v(t)
```

The  state space model :

```
x(t+1) = Ax(t) + w(t)

y(t) = Cx(t) + v(t)

w(t) = N(0,Q) is the driving process noise 

v(t) = N(0,R)  is the measurement noise
```

Re-writing the AR model as State Space representation:

[image: SS_AR]

Can somebody please point out where I have done wrong so that the code works.  I have followed most of the sequence and structure from https://github.com/cswetenham/pmr/blob/master/toolboxes/lds/lds.m#L110

(1) Eq(26) needs an initial value for $x0$. I supplied `x0 = mean(x,2)` to the function `Predict`. I have a doubt in this. Will `x0` and hence `initx` be the mean of the observation `y` which gives a scalar or will it be 2 values (2 rows by 1 column) since the state space is AR(2). I am not sure about this.

(2) If I take `x0 = mean(x,2)` and   Commenting off the Code after Kalman Filtering gives proper results for state estimation. It is only from smoothing that the parameter estimation is not correct. It is not correct because the new `x0 = initx = x1sum/N` becomes a scalar whereas when initializing it was a 2 by 1 matrix, where each row is the state.

```
%%% Matlab script to simulate data and process usiung Kalman for the state
%%% estimation of AR(2) time series.:  y(t) =  0.195 *y(t-1) - 0.95*y(t-2) + excite_input(t);
% Linear system representation
% x_n+1 = A x_n + Bw_n
% y_n = Cx_n + v_n
% w = N(0,Q); v = N(0,R)
clc
clear all

T = 100;
order = 2;
  a1 = 0.195;
  a2 = -0.95;

A = [ a1  a2;
      1 0 ];
C = [ 1 0 ];
B = [1;
      0];


 x =[ rand(order,1) zeros(order,T-1)];% a sequence of 100 2-d vectors



sigma_2_w =1;
sigma_2_v = 0.01;



Q=eye(order);
P=Q;



%Simulate the steady state covariance matrix P
%P = A*P*A' + B*sqrt(sigma_2_w)*B';
 P = dlyap(A,B*B');

%Simulate AR model time series, x;


sqrtW=sqrtm(sigma_2_w);
excite_input=B*sqrtW*randn(1,T);
for t = 1:T-1
    x(:,t+1) = A*x(:,t) + excite_input(t+1);
end

%noisy observation

y = C*x + sqrt(sigma_2_v)*randn(1,T);



R  = sigma_2_v ;

z = y;
%X= x';
 x0=mean(x,2);
 YHAT = zeros(1,T);
 XHAT = zeros(2,T+1);

LL=[];
converged = 0;
previous_loglik = -Inf;
Y =y;
z = Y;


N = T;
max_iter = 500;
num_iter = 0;
initx = x0;
% V1 = var(initx);
loglik = 0;
V1 = P;
 while ~converged & (num_iter <= max_iter)
  initx = x0;

  k = length(initx);
  I=eye(k);
  xtt=zeros(2,T);   Vtt=zeros(2,2,T); xtt1=zeros(2,T); Vtt1=zeros(2,2,T); xhat_s = zeros(2,T);
  xtT=zeros(2,T); VtT=zeros(2,2,T); J=zeros(2,2,T); Vtt1T=zeros(2,2,T);  Ptsum = 0;
  x1sum = 0;
  P1sum = 0;
  A1=zeros(k);
  A2=zeros(k);
  XPred = zeros(2,T);
  Ptsum=zeros(k);
  xhat = zeros(2,1);
  Pcov = zeros(k,k);
  Kcur = 0;
  YX = 0;

%KAlman Filtering

for i =1:T

[xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,V1, A, Q);
[nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z(i), C, R);
[xnew, P, yhat, KalmanGain] = innovation_update_LDS(A, xpred, Ppred, V1, nu, S, C);
YHAT(i) = yhat;
Phat(i) = sqrt(C*P*C');
xtt(:,i) = xnew;  %xtt is the filtered state
Vtt(:,:,i) = P; %filtered covariance
Vtt1(:,:,i) = Ppred;
XPred(:,i) = A*xtt(:,i);


end 

KC = KalmanGain*C;

% 
% %Kalman Smoothing
% 
% 

KT = KalmanGain;

% %backward pass gets you E[x(t)|y(1:T)] from E[x(t)|y(1:t)]
t=T;
xtT(:,t) = xtt(:,t);
VtT(:,:,t) = Vtt(:,:,t);


% %SMOOTHING
 for t=(T-1):-1:1
     Vtt1(:,:,t) = A*Vtt(:,:,t)*A' + Q;
     J(:,:,t) = Vtt(:,:,t)*A'*inv(Vtt1(:,:,t+1)); %Eq(31)
     xtT(:,t) =  xtt(:,t) + ((xtT(:,t+1)- XPred(:,t))'*J(:,:,t))';  % Eq(32) xsmooth  modified the transpose
     VtT(:,:,t) = Vtt(:,:,t) + J(:,:,t)*(VtT(:,:,t+1)-Vtt1(:,:,t+1))*J(:,:,t)';  % Eq(33) Vsmooth or Psmooth
     Pt=VtT(:,:,t) + xtT(:,t)*xtT(:,t)'; 
     Ptsum=Ptsum+Pt;
     YX = YX+Y(:,t)'*xtT(:,t);  %For Eq(14)
      x1sum = x1sum + xtT(:,1);
    %  gama2 = gama2 + Pt - xtT(:,1)*xtT(:,1)' - VtT(:,:,1);

end
% Pt = VtT + xtT'*xtT;

% Pt = VtT(:,:,t) + xtT(:,t)'*xtT(:,t);  %P_t,t-1 = V_t,t-1^T + x_t^T * x_t^T'


 Sum_Pt_2T= Ptsum - Pt;  %A3  gama2
 A2= Ptsum + A2; %gama1

xhat_s = xtT; %smoothed estimate of x(t)


t= T;
 Pcov=(eye(2)-KC)*A*Vtt(:,:,t-1);
 A1=A1+Pcov+xtT(:,t)'*xtT(:,t-1);


for t= (T-1):-1:2
 Pcov =(Vtt(:,:,t) + J(:,:,t)*(Pcov - A*Vtt(:,:,t)))*J(:,:,t-1)';  %Eq(34)
 A1 = A1+Pcov+xtT(:,t)'*xtT(:,t-1);
 end; 

Rterm = (Y - C*xtt);
R_result = 0.5*Rterm' * inv(R)* Rterm;
R_sum_result = sum(sum(R_result));

Qterm = xtt(:,2:T)-(A*xtt(:,1:(T-1)));
Q_result = 0.5*Qterm' * inv(Q) * Qterm;
Q_sum_result = sum(sum(Q_result));

V1term = (xtt(:,1) -initx);
V1_result = 0.5 * V1term' * inv(V1) * V1term;

loglik_t = - R_sum_result - 0.5*T*log(det(R)) - Q_sum_result - 0.5*(T-1)*log(det(Q)) -  V1_result - 0.5*log(det(V1)) - 0.5*T*log(2*pi);



%STEP 2 Re-estimate B,Q,R,initx,initV1 via ML given x(t) estimate
 C=YX'*inv(Ptsum)/N;
 A=A1*inv(A2); 
 R1term = sum(Y.*Y)'/(T);
 R2term = diag(C*YX)/T;
 R = R1term - R2term;  % R = (1/T)*sum(Y.*Y - C.*xhat_s.*Y');
 Q=(1/(T-1))*diag(diag((Sum_Pt_2T-A*(A1')))); 
initx = x1sum/N;
x0 = initx;
V1 = Pt(:,:,1) - initx*initx';
  LL=[LL loglik_t];
  num_iter = num_iter+1
converged = em_converged(loglik, previous_loglik); %subfunction below
previous_loglik = loglik_t;


 end %while not converged
A

C
Q
R

function [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,P, A, Q)
xpred = A*x0;
Ppred = A*P*A' + Q;
end

function [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, y, C, R)
nu = y - C*xpred; %% innovation

S = R + C*Ppred*C'; %% innovation covariance

end

function [xnew, Pnew, yhat, K] = innovation_update_LDS(A,xpred, Ppred,V1, nu, S, C)
% invP=inv(S);
% K = Ppred*C'*invP; %% Kalman gain
% xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
% Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance
% yhat = C*xnew; % Observed value at time step i, assuming inferred state xnew
% xhat = A*xnew + K*nu;

K = Ppred*C'*inv(S); %% Kalman gain 2 rows 1 col (scalar
xnew = xpred + K*nu; %% new state
Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance
 yhat = C*xnew;
VVnew = (eye(2) - K*C)*A*V1;

end

function converged = em_converged(loglik, previous_loglik, threshold)
% EM_CONVERGED Has EM converged?
% [converged, decrease] = em_converged(loglik, previous_loglik, threshold)
%
% We have converged if
% |f(t) - f(t-1)| / avg < threshold,
% where avg = (|f(t)| + |f(t-1)|)/2 and f is log lik.
% threshold defaults to 1e-4.
% This stopping criterion is from Numerical Recipes in C p42
if nargin < 3
threshold = 1e-4;
end
%log likelihood should increase
if loglik - previous_loglik < -1e-3 % allow for a little imprecision
fprintf(1, '******likelihood decreased from %6.4f to %6.4f!\n', previous_loglik,loglik);
end
delta_loglik = abs(loglik - previous_loglik);
avg_loglik = (abs(loglik) + abs(previous_loglik) + eps)/2;
if (delta_loglik / avg_loglik) < threshold
converged = 1
else converged = 0
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use e.g. https://code.google.com/p/bnt/source/browse/trunk/Kalman/learn_kalman.m?

Comment: I need to modify a lot of the code to suit my model. The best way to understand the complexities and what is happening is to implement it myself. Moreover, my models are not restricted to regression and AR. I found Kevin Murphy's implementation to be very rigid. Also, the calculation of the log-likelihood is very weird; it does not follow any formula. Hence, my tedious practice of implementing all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first place I always start when looking at kalman code is the update step, specifically the covariance update. In your code its `innovation_update_LDS`

The standard form you are using is `Pnew = Ppred - Ppred*K*C; %% new covariance` this is incorrect, it should be `Pnew = Ppred - K*C*Ppred` or more commonly `Pnew = (I - K*C)*Ppred;` where `I=eye(len(K));`

besides that point, I would never use that form of the equation either.Use "[Josephs form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)"

```
Pnew = (eye(2) - K*C) * Ppred * (eye(2)-K*C)' + K*R*K';
```

This form is computationally stable. It guarantees the matrix will stay symmetric as it should. Using the standard form this isn't guaranteed, it has to do with rounding errors in computers but after many iterations, or whenusing a state space with a large number of features, the covariance matrix becomes nonsymmetric and incurs huge errors and ultimately cause the filter not to follow the expected trajectory at all.

Three also seems to be a few errors in you %KAlman Filtering section. I think it should look more like this

```
%KAlman Filtering

for i =1:T
    if (i==1)
        [xpred, Ppred] = predict(x0,V1, A, Q);
    else
        [xpred, Ppred] = predict(xtt(:,i-1),Vtt(:,:,i-1), A, Q);
    end
    [nu, S] = innovation(xpred, Ppred, z(i), C, R);
    [xnew, Pnew, yhat, KalmanGain] = innovation_update_LDS(A, xpred, Ppred, V1, nu, S, C, R);
    YHAT(i) = yhat;
    Phat(i) = sqrt(C*Pnew*C');
    xtt(:,i) = xnew;  %xtt is the filtered state
    Vtt(:,:,i) = Pnew(:,:); %filtered covariance
end
```

there may have been more errors, but this is all I have time to find. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your effort & time to go through the problem. Thank you for introducing the Josephs form. One major problem with the code & in my understanding is in the Maximization step.  initx variable is substituted by x0. Initialization of x0 = mean(x,2). But x is hidden so how come I can take its mean? Another thing is the likelihood and the estimates are not getting updated so all the values are NaN. Should I update the log likelihood expression after the smoothing step and plug in the smoothed values into the log-likelihood Or just use the filtered states in the loglikelihood?

Comment: Will you be going through the entire code to correct it or should I get back with whatever corrections I can do at my end before the bounty expires and then maybe you can help me out from that point onwards?

Comment: well i think you can use `x0=mean(x,2)` only because in this particular situation you have all X values. in the real world. you would use some other value. Pehaps 0,0 the nice thing is that the since the kalman filter is "intelligent" so with reasonable initialization, it should converge to the actual state after just a few iterations.  I don't know what the point of EM is here (I can't read the paper) so i don't know where LLF should be, my guess is use updated values. I see your EM changes values used by the kalman filter. 2 things editing 1 set of values sounds like trouble to me.